# IP set to block access to exim and dovecot

Tags: email, iptables, ipset

I have created a ipset with a bunch of IPs that I want to block access to dovecot and exim.

The ipset is called "bannedIPs" and have been added to iptables using this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -m set --set bannedIPs src -j DROP
```

my question is:

- Are these rules correct? Will they block IPs on the bannedIPs ipset from accessing exim and dovecots on all ports of these services?

Comment: Yes, why you suspect that?

Comment: because I see the same IPs trying to access dovecot and/or exim on /var/log/maillog and/or /var/log/exim/mainlog after they have been added to the set. Once I have a new IP I just add it to the ipset using  **ipset -A bannedIPS #.#.#.#**. Is adding an IP to ipset all I have to do to block that IP or do I have to reload the ipset or whatever after adding a new IP?

Comment: Nope, it's loaded automatically ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

You didn't tell us what service you are running, imap(s) or pop, smtp(s) etc., and if it's all using the default port.

But, to verify that you've collected all necessary ports, run i.e `netstat -luantp` to get a list of listening ports. Then compare the list of ports against it.

Also, consider put these rules into a single one,

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,465,110,143,993,995 -m set --match-set bannedIPs src -j DROP`

To save / restore ipset lists, try `ipset save > ipset.rules` and `ipset restore < ipset.rules`

Comment: yes, dovecot and exim are using default ports. I will try your multiple rule

Comment: ah, just to clear one thing. As far as I know these ipset/iptables rules are cleared if you shutdown/restart a machine. Is there a way to save all these rules and ipset and reload them automatically after a restart?

Comment: @DigitalRobot updated answer

Comment: thanks. So I guess all saving/restore are always manual, unless I add a script to automate that, right? I thought there was a way to automatically load iptables with all ipsets defined after a restart. Thanks

Comment: @DigitalRobot nope, prepare your own init script